# How to do "docker load" for multiple tar files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have list of .tar docker image files , I have tried loading docker images using below commands

1. `docker load -i *.tar`
2. `docker load -i alldockerimages.tar`

where `alldockerimages.tar` contains all individual tar files .

Let me know how we can load multiple tar files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First I attempted to use the glob expression approach you first described:

```
# download some images to play with
docker pull alpine
docker pull nginx:alpine

# stream the images to disk as tarballs
docker save alpine > alpine.tar
docker save nginx:alpine > nginx.tar

# delete the images so we can attempt to load them from scratch
docker rmi alpine nginx:alpine

# issue the load command to try and load all images at once
cat *.tar | docker load
```

Unfortunately this only resulted in `alpine.tar` being loaded. It was my (presumably faulty) understanding that the glob expression would be expanded and ultimately cause the `docker load` command to be run for every file into which the glob expression expanded.

Therefore, one has to use a shell `for` loop to load all tarballs sequentially:

```
for f in *.tar; do
    cat $f | docker load
done
```

Comment: I use this: `mkdir -p myFolder && tar xvf BigFileWithManyImages.tar -C $_ && for f in $_/images/*.tar.gz; do docker load -i $f ; done1`

Answer (score 18):

Using xargs:

`ls -1 *.tar | xargs --no-run-if-empty -L 1 docker load -i`

(A previous revision left off the -i flag to "docker load".)

Comment: Add a `-i` to the end and this works. Also, `sudo` before docker if you need to run docker as root.

Answer (score 1):

Use the script described in [save-load-docker-images.sh](https://gist.github.com/mmrko/78a071d0ff2062cb199a852e2469586f) to save or load the images. For your case it would be

```
./save-load-docker-images.sh load -d <directory-location>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next option using find:

`find -type f -name "*.tar" -exec docker load --input "{}" \;`